# PHP Cant access object property

Tags: php, object

I get some config options from Json_decode, and obtain this object :

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'db' => string 'Colleges' (length=8)
  public 'table' => string 'interventions' (length=13)
  public 'key' => string 'id_inter' (length=8)
  public 'rootdir' => string '/Users/mj/Sites/Datatable' (length=25)
  public 'servername ' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  public 'username ' => string 'root' (length=4)
  public 'password ' => string '*********' (length=9)
```

the json_last_error() is 0, so I think the object is valid.

However, I cant access any property of the object...

`( ! ) Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$servername in /Users/mj/Sites/EDIMAKE2/edimake.php on line 37`

Line 37 is here:

`echo "globserver = ".$GlobConfig->servername;`

Any idea before I recode the whole thing using associative arrays ?

Thanks in advance
Michel

Comment: Show the code where you assign json_decode to the object

Comment: ... and the original JSON string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOPS
thanks for pointing me in right direction.
Answer is in the question :

```
  public 'servername ' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  public 'username ' => string 'root' (length=4)
  public 'password ' => string '*********' (length=9)
```

Trailing space after each key.....
Sorry
Michel